# Is it possible to create users with drush 2?

Tags: drupal, drush

I like to create users from a bash script via drush.
Is it possible with a plain drush 2.x?
If not, what extensions or drush version is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drush 2.x does not natively have the capability to add users and it doesn't look like there is any work on getting it to work with drush 2.x. There is a patch for 3.x at http://drupal.org/files/issues/user.drush_.inc__8.patch
(notes at http://drupal.org/project/drush_user)

Also, this feature will be included in drush4.

Seems like your best solution would be to upgrade to drush3.x or see if you can hack the patch to work with 2.x (which sounds like a pretty bad idea)

Answer (score 0):

In later Drush versions you can create users with the command user-create (alias **ucrt**):

```
drush user-create johnny
```